# how do i find the height of a triangle when all i am given is the angle of elevation and the length of the triangle

Tags: geometry

I need help in figuring out how to find the height from a spotlight to the ceiling of some clouds if from a theodolite to the spotlight is 83m and the angle of elevation is 62.7°.

Comment: use trigonometry.

Comment: I'm a sophemore in high school I haven't learned trigonometry yet.

Comment: if you've been assigned this problem, I'm guessing you have but don't know you have.

Comment: I have and thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measurement of altitude is vertical, so you have a right triangle with hypotenuse 83 and one angle 62.7 degrees.  Look up the definitions of sine and cosine.  Which should you apply?

Comment: 83 Is the shortest side. Right angle is on bottom left corner. Therefore would i apply tangent?

Comment: If the horizontal side is 83, you need the tangent of 62.7.  You didn't define what the theodolite was looking at-I thought it was the cloud.  Looks like you got it by your acceptance.

Comment: I did. Your having me look at the definitions really made me think about what I needed to use. Thank you.